# Integrate a lambda list function in Python

Tags: python, math, scipy

In Python I'm trying

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
time_start = 0
fun = lambda time: [cos(time), sin(time)]
integral = lambda time: quad(fun, time_start, time)
```

and would like the program to return `integral` as a list of which the elements are the element wise integration of `fun`, so `[quad(cos, time_start, time), quad(sin, time_start, time)]`.

I, however, get `TypeError: must be real number, not list`.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `quad` on a function that returns a list of two functions--instead, use it twice on two functions then compose the results into a list. [The documentation for scipy.integrate.quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) gives the possible signatures for the function to be integrated, and each signature shows that the function must return a `double` value (called `float` in Python), not a list.

If you cannot change the definitions of `time_start` or `fun` or the parameters or return value of `integral`, you could use this code.

```
from math import cos, sin
from scipy.integrate import quad

# Global variables and constants used in function `integral`
time_start = 0
fun = lambda time: [cos(time), sin(time)]

# The desired function
def integral(time):
    """Return a list of two items containing the integrals of the two
    components of the `fun` function from `start_time` to `time`.
    """
    def fun0(time):
        return fun(time)[0]
    def fun1(time):
        return fun(time)[1]

    integral0 = quad(fun0, time_start, time)[0]
    integral1 = quad(fun1, time_start, time)[0]
    return [integral0, integral1]
```

Then the result of the statement

```
print(integral(0), integral(pi/2), integral(pi))
```

is

```
[0.0, 0.0] [0.9999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999] [3.6775933888827275e-17, 2.0]
```

which is what you want, within precision error.

---

By the way, using a `lambda` expression to create a function then assigning it to a name is considered to be poor programming practice in Python. [See here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), the fifth bullet point. Use a regular `def` block instead:

```
def fun(time):
    return [cos(time), sin(time)]

def integral(time):
    # as shown above
```

Of course, the use of `time_start` and `fun` as global variables, rather than as parameters of `integral`, is also bad practice, but I kept to the way you used them.